# FFMpeg How to extract individual audio channels from wav/.w64 and insert in .mxf with track tags

Tags: ffmpeg, wav

Hi my problem is I have 2 .w64 files (extended wav format) each file has 16 mono channels of audio. I want to be able to extract specific channels of audio from each of those .w64 files and insert those channels into an .mxf file as separate single channel mono audio streams and to be additionally able to set the Tag information on those audio streams. I have tried using -map and so on but it seems to take all the channels from the .w64 files and insert a single audio stream of 16 channels. I apologise in advance as I'm very new to ffmpeg and thanks in advance for any advice any of you can offer. This is all specific to command line usage on windows.
All the best

> ffmpeg  -i "D:\Media\AUDIO_0.W64" -i "D:\media\NO_AUDIO.mxf" -c copy -map 0:0:0 -map 0:0:1 -map 0:0:2 -acodec pcm_s24le -map 1:0  "D:\media\out.mxf"

```
ffmpeg version N-67838-g4388e78 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 19 2014 22:02:08 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 14.100 / 54. 14.100
  libavcodec     56. 12.101 / 56. 12.101
  libavformat    56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[w64 @ 0481c580] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, w64, from 'D:\Media\AUDIO_0.W64':
  Duration: 00:01:02.56, bitrate: 18432 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 16 channels
, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s
[mxf @ 048890e0] index entry 1564 + TemporalOffset 1 = 1565, which is out of bou
nds
Input #1, mxf, from 'D:\media\NO_AUDIO.mxf':
  Metadata:
    uid             : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0000
    generation_uid  : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0001
    company_name    : FFmpeg
    product_name    : OP1a Muxer
    product_version : 57.56.100
    product_uid     : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0002
    modification_date: 0000-01-01 00:00:00
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:01:02.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2404 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR16:9], max. 50000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
File 'D:\media\out.mxf' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y

[mxf @ 04891c60] there must be exactly one video stream and it must be the first
 one
Output #0, mxf, to 'D:\media\out.mxf':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.14.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.12.101 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.12.101 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.12.101 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:3: Video: mpeg2video, yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, max. 50000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s24le (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s24le (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (pcm_s24le (native) -> pcm_s24le (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:3 (copy)

Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Error
number -1 occurred
```

Comment: Show the command you ran and its full console output.

Comment: Your `ffmpeg` is old. You should update. See the [download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your mapping is messed up

The error message states, "there must be exactly one video stream and it must be the first one". MXF is picky, so you have to make sure to map the video first because the mapping order will determine the stream order in the output.

Secondly, you're attempting to use `-map` for audio channel selection, but it doesn't work like that: you have to add `-map_channel` or the pan audio filter.

## -map_channel

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Media\AUDIO_0.W64" -i "D:\media\NO_AUDIO.mxf" \
       -map 1:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a \
       -map_channel 0.0.0:0.1 \
       -map_channel 0.0.1:0.2 \
       -map_channel 0.0.2:0.3 \
       -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s24le \
       -shortest "D:\media\out.mxf"
```

## pan filter

Or you can use the [pan audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) instead of `-map_channel`:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Media\AUDIO_0.W64" -i "D:\media\NO_AUDIO.mxf" \
       -filter_complex "[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c1[a1];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c2[a2]" \
       -map 1:v -map "[a0]" -map "[a1]" -map "[a2]" \
       -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s24le 
       -shortest "D:\media\out.mxf"
```

I prefer using pan. Once you get the hang of pan there is more flexibility, and `-map_channel` is just using pan anyway.

## metadata

You didn't specify what metadata you wanted to add to each stream so I'll just give a generic example. To add a metadata field named *key* with a value named *value* to the third audio stream:

```
-metadata:s:a:2 key=value
```

I'm not sure what MXF supports, or what the MXF muxer supports, so you may have to experiment.

Comment: Wow fantastic, Thank you very much for this, I would never have worked this out on my own. As regards the metadata its just the language tag for the audio stream in the mxf file. "ENG", "GER" etc.

Comment: out of curiosity is there a shortcut for say take all those audio channels in the audio file and add them as individual audio streams in the .mxf?.

Comment: @Vince Not that I know of. You'll have to use `-map_channel` or the pan or channelsplit filters.